# How to change cover art in mp3 file using Jaudiotagger

Tags: java, android

I can successfully change mp3 tags using Jaudiotagger Java library in android but can not change the cover art. I think the problem is getting image from assets folder

Here is my code

```
TagOptionSingleton.getInstance().setAndroid(true);
AudioFile f =AudioFileIO.read(file_path_to_mp3); 
Tag tag=f.getTag();
tag.setField(FieldKey.ARTIST,artist);
Artwork cover=ArtworkFactory.createArtworkFromFile(new File("file:///android_asset/www/img/logo.png")); 
tag.setField(cover);        
f.commit();
```

What am I doing wrong ?